# Handle windows lock/unlock events in .net core

Tags: windows, events, .net-core, locking, system

In the .Net Framework there is an event that, when handled, you could log  was lock/unlock events on an account. It is this one:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch
```

I can't find this in .Net core. Does anyone know what the equivalent in .Net Core is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this event is platform specific, it probably wouldn't the part of .Net Standard, so you can't find it in .Net Core. According the [APIs of .Net](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch), they do not have plans for introducing this class.

So, you may try to create a platform-specific library with `SessionSwitch` code, but that wouldn't run on other platforms rather than Windows, and put your general logic into .Net Standard library so [you can use that either from .Net Core app and .Net Framework app](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx).

Other way is to use Mono, which contain such events in it.